# What does the Pakistan election mean for the US?

Tags: united-states, election, pakistan

Pakistan is an important ally in South Asia to the US, but the relationship isn't stable, particularly not recently due to the US drone program and some harsh words from Trump.

With the upcoming elections in Pakistan in mind, what outcome would be the most favorable to the US? Has the US voiced any support for any particular party, be it the incumbent or a new challenger? In turn, what have the political parties said about the US, i.e. what are their positions on US-Pakistan relations?